# How can I prove or disprove that the formula $2^{2{^{2^{2^2\dots}}}}+1$ gives a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

I could calculate the following
$$2+1=3$$
$$2^2+1=5$$
$$2^{2^2}+1=17$$
$$2^{2{^{2^2}}}+1=65537$$

Now how can I prove or disprove the formula always gives a prime number

Comment: Very little is known about the prime-ness of $2^{2^n}+1$ in general, and these are all of this form. It is not even known that there are infinitely many primes of this more limited form - indeed, the only such "Fermat primes" currently known are $n=0,1,2,3,4.$ So you'll have a hard time getting much help on this site proving the above.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number

Comment: @E.H.E Come on! You can't be this naive.

Comment: Also, this appears to be a duplicate of your own question.

Answer (score 3):

According to the OEIS ([here](http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C5%2C17%2C65537&language=english&go=Search)) the fifth term in this sequence,

$$2^{65536} + 1$$

is divisible by 825753601.  Therefore, not all such numbers are prime.

The OEIS link above provides some references on this sequence.  As Thomas Andrews states in his comment, this is a subsequence of the Fermat numbers, and not much is known.

Answer (score 2):

Entering the following into Sage:

```
(2^2^2^2^2+1).is_prime()
```

yields

```
False
```

(Also, [WolframAlpha says "unknown" when asked that question](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+2%5E2%5E2%5E2%5E2%2B1+prime).)

Therefore, the formula does not always give a prime number.